# Why am I able to change string literal defined inside a struct?

Tags: c, string, struct, char, literals

```
typedef struct node
{
    char *name;
}
node;

int main(void)
{
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *table[2];

    table[0] = temp;
    table[0]->name = "tamesh";
    
    printf("%c \n",  toupper(table[0]->name[0]));
}
```

I am able to print the output "T". But technically I should not be able to modify a string literal right?

Comment: _"technically i should not be able to modify a string literal right?"_ - Trying to modify a string literal makes the program have undefined behavior. I don't see that you try doing that though.

Comment: What makes you think that you are "able to modify a string literal"? You are only printing the `char` return value of a called function. You do not change the literal, the function (e.g. according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper ) doesn't either.

Comment: `toupper` doesn't take a string as input in the first place, so maybe just study what that function does.

Comment: `table[0]->name[0] = toupper(table[0]->name[0]);` would be an attempt to modify the string literal. You're not doing that in your code. (The array of structs accessed through a pointer is irrelevant... You can't outsmart the smart people who write compilers, so don't waste time trying, unless you've got time to burn...)

Comment: `int x = 6; printf("%d\n", x*7); /* you are not modifying x */`

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to do that (anything which looks like that is undefined behaviour), and you do not.
You are only printing the `char` return value of a called function. You do not change the string literal; the called function (e.g. according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper ) doesn't either.

Answer (score 1):

On many systems like Linux, string literals are grouped into a read-only section. In this context, a tool like `objdump` provides the ability to look at the content of the generated object after compilation/linking. For example, if the resulting executable is named *str*, the following is output to show that the string literal is stored in a section called ".rodata" (which means read-only data):

```
$ objdump -s str

str:     file format elf64-x86-64
[...]
Contents of section .rodata:
 2000 01000200 74616d65 73680025 63200a00  ....tamesh.%c ..
[...]
```

In the above dump, we can see that even the string literal "%c \n" passed to `printf()` is located into this section.
At execution time, the corresponding memory area will be write protected. Any attempt to write into this section will result into a segmentation violation error.
As said in the comments and other answers, your original code does not modify the string, it merely passes the first char of the string to `toupper()` which displays the upper case translation of its parameter. Let's do a real modification of the string:

```c
#include <stdio.h>  // For printf()
#include <ctype.h>  // For toupper()
#include <stdlib.h> // For malloc()

typedef struct node
{
    char *name;
}
node;

int main(void)
{
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *table[2];

    table[0] = temp;
    table[0]->name = "tamesh";
    
    printf("%c \n",  toupper(table[0]->name[0]));

    table[0]->name[0] = 'T';

    return 0;
}
```

The execution triggers a segmentation fault error:

```
$ gcc -g str.c -o str
$ ./str
T 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The analysis of the resulting core file with a debugger like `gdb` shows that the crash occured at the line where we tried to modify the string:

```
$ gdb str core
[...]
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from str...
[New LWP 7273]
Core was generated by `./str'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  main () at str.c:21
21      table[0]->name[0] = 'T';
(gdb) where
#0  main () at str.c:21
(gdb)
```

Comment: Whether string literals are put into a read-only section is implementation-dependent. The C standard does not require it. Students often work on general-purpose multiuser systems in which string literals are put into read-only sections, but they should be aware they are working on a system with these “guard rails,” and other platforms they may work on someday might not do that.

Comment: Totally agree with you @EricPostpischil. I posted my answer for a Linux environment context with all the required guards. I added a precision at the beginning of the answer.